# How can I add a class to a nav li depending on URL?

Tags: functions, filters

I'm trying to add a .current-menu-item class to a li when on a specific url "/portfolio/". I can achieve this with jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
  if(/portfolio/.test(loc)) {
    $('#menu-item-33').addClass('current-menu-item');
  }
});
```

However would like to do with PHP. This what I have so far:

```
function add_class_to_specific_menu_items( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    // check if the item is set to target="_blank"
    if ( $item->url == '/portfolio/' ) {
      // add the desired attributes:
      $atts['class'] = 'current-menu-item';
    }
    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_class_to_specific_menu_items', 10, 3 );
```

Not sure if this is viable and/or if I can have it add the class to a specific li "#menu-item-33

Comment: Hi! Why you dont want to add a class to menu item on menu edit page in wp admin?

Comment: Doesn't WP do this automatically if you've set the nav menu and the page correctly?

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes you are correct, however /portfolio/ items aren't part of a archive page, so there is no current-menu-ancestor or current-page-ancestor classes on the li.

Comment: couldn't you _make them_ be a part of an archive? It sounds like `/portfolio` is a page template and you're using a secondary post loop to display things, rather than using a CPT with a rewrite rule of `/portfolio/xxxxxxx` and `archive-portfolio.php`

Comment: @TomJNowell if I could do that I would. /portfolio is not a page template. I inherited this site and am just trying to come up with a solution.

Comment: what is `/portfolio`? Or is it because the nav menu link isn't a post archive but a custom URL that leads to the post archive?

Comment: @TomJNowell That's correct. The nav menu link isn't a post archive but a custom URL that leads to the post archive.

Comment: [WordPress already tries to apply the `current-menu-item` class to "Custom"-type nav links based on URL matching](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/270f2011f8ec7265c3f4ddce39c77ef5b496ed1c/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L464). Any approximate re-implementation of this behavior as a solution to this question would likely prove inferior to what's in core. It would be better to expand upon your use-case and why the core implementation is insufficient for your needs, or perhaps troubleshoot why the core behavior is not applying if indeed it does not appear to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Here is the solution.

### To set it up:

Paste the following at the bottom of the file `functions.php` in the folder of your current theme.

#### Edit by the  in the code`

`$when_on_one_of_these_page_slugs` should be an array of strings. The strings are the **slugs** of the pages on where you want the rule to kick in. The script will kick in the rule if you are on:

- One of these slugs.
- A child of any of these slugs.

#### Edit by the  in the code:

`$change_these_nav_menu_items` should be a list of menu item id's, of the item you want to look selected, when the rule kicks in.

You can find the ID of the menu in dev tools by right clicking on the menu item and choose "inspect element". You will see the source code of the generated page, and you will find the item ID in the `<li>` tag wrapping the `<a>` of the item you inspected.

[image]

```php
/**
 * Makes specific menu item look active when visiting a certain page
 *
 * @param array $wp_nav_meny Array of items from a WP Nav Menu.
 *
 * @return array modified array of WP Nave Menu items.
 * @see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/389050/how-can-i-add-a-class-to-a-nav-li-depending-on-url
 */
function make_x_active_when_on_y( array $wp_nav_meny ) {


    //  Set an array of page slug (strings) to trigger the rule.
    $when_on_one_of_these_page_slugs = array( 'portfolio', 'add-any-slug-that-should-trigger-the-rule');
    //  Set an array menu item id's (ints) to apply the rule to.
    $change_these_nav_menu_items = array( 33, 999);

    // Get the ID's of the pages we added in the setting.
    $post_ids_to_trigger_rule = wp_list_pluck(array_map('get_page_by_path',  $when_on_one_of_these_page_slugs ), 'ID');
    // Get all the ancestors of the page we are curently visiting.
    $ancestors_of_current_page = get_post_ancestors(get_queried_object_id());
    // Add the current page into the array of ancestors.
    array_push($ancestors_of_current_page, get_the_ID());

    $new_menu = array();

    // Loop through the nav menu items.
    foreach ( $wp_nav_meny as $menu_item ) {
        /*
         * If the ID of the current page, or any of it's ancestors,
         * exists in the array of ID's that should trigger the rule,
         * AND
         * The current item ID in the loop, is in the array if nav menu
         * item id's that sould get the "current-menu-item" class.
         */
        if ( array_intersect($post_ids_to_trigger_rule, $ancestors_of_current_page) && in_array( (int) $menu_item->ID, $change_these_nav_menu_items, true ) ) {
            $menu_item->classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
        }
        $new_menu[] = $menu_item;
    }
    return $new_menu;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'make_x_active_when_on_y' );
```

### How it works

When you visit a page that has the slug you set at the , or a page that has that page as an ancestor, then the rule kick in.

**The rule** is that the menu item that you set at  will have the class `current-menu-item`.

Below you can see a recording of the result.

This is a completely fresh installation of **WordPress 5.7.2**, running **PHP 7.4.1**. No plugins installed. The theme is **twentytwentyone** (the ones that is shipped with WordPress).

**My config looked like this:**

```
$when_on_one_of_these_page_slugs = array( 'portfolio'); // The slug of my portfolio page.
$change_these_nav_menu_items = array( 24 ); // The item ID of my "A link to Google"-menu item.
```

[image: In action]

Comment: A silly technicality here, but food for thought. It looks like the JS provided by the author cares more about if the slug is present in the URL, not if the menu item has the slug.  This matters because (in example) the post has the slug "portfolio" but the URL is "/my/fancy/url".  In that case, the author is representing that they do not want the list item to have the class specified.  Or if the menu item is of the slug "yo-madoff" but the URI is "/what/happened/to/my/401k/portfolio/i/m/broke" your code wouldn't add the class though the author's JS represents it should.

Comment: My code does exactly what the author asked for. How exactly do you mean that you would have the slug "portfolio", but not have portfolio in the url? The slug of a post is the unique identifier, and the last part of the URL. In the case of "/my/fancy/url/", the slug would be "url".

If you try to change the slug of a post in WordPress to "my/fancy/url", it would save it as "my-fancy-url".

Comment: Thanks @FabianMossberg. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @moodyjive: what is it that doesn't work with it? I jus tried it in a clean installation of WP, and it kicks in perfectly. Make sure you keep it `portfolio` and not `/portfolio/` in the slug.

Also, note that it will only kick in on the page with the slug `portfolio`, not on it's children. Also, make sure `$change_these_nav_menu_items` is an array, and that the ID in that array is the menu item id, not the post ID. You can find the menu item ID by using the inspector on the menu item element, and look at the `<li>` tag, it will have an attribute `id="menu-item-123"`, where 123 is the id.

Comment: @FabianMossberg I need it to work with children "portfolio/xxxxxx". And yes I used the code exactly as sent and I used the same id that is on the li.

Comment: I tried it on a completely fresh installation of Wordpress and it works perfectly. Maybe you have some of the other suggestions from this thread active in your code as well? If so, comment those out and just run this one. I also **updated** the code so that it kicks in as long as your targeted slug is the current page **or among it's ancestors**. I also added **screenshots**, **videos** and a better explanation on how to find the settings ✌️

Comment: @FabianMossberg II just want to thank you for the way you presented this. It is very clear and detailed and while I don't totally understand PHP, it makes perfect sense to me. Unfortunately it still doesn't work for me, but none of the solutions are working (BTW - I don't have multiple solutions in - I try each individually). There must be some conflict with a plugin or the theme.

Comment: @moodyjive: I believe my solution does exactly what you asked about (at least it does it on Installations without any themes or plugins, try it yourself).  If i so, it would be great if you ticked the checkbox that this is the correct answer!

Comment: Beautiful formatting and inline documentation indeed!

Comment: Thanks @bosco , I use **phpcs** and the [WordPress Coding Standards](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards) with automatic formatting in **VS Code**, it helps me to keep my code consistent and beautiful automatically. ✌️

Answer (score 0):

Try the following tested solutions they are working **100%** on the frontend screen because both solutions are based on the wp filter hook **[wp_get_nav_menu_items](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_nav_menu_items/)** which is executed where the **[wp_get_nav_menu_items()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/)** function is called.

**Solution 01:** Add CSS class by comparing menu item **ID**

```
function add_class_to_specific_menu_items( $items, $menu, $args ){
    foreach ( $items as $index => $menu_item ){
        // conditional statement to compare the menu-item id
        if( $menu_item->ID == 33 ){
              // conditional statement to check the current url is same
              if( get_permalink() == $menu_item->url ){
                  $menu_item->classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
              }     
        }
    }
  return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'add_class_to_specific_menu_items', 10, 3);
```

**Solution 02:** Add CSS class by comparing menu item **URL**

```
function add_class_to_specific_menu_items( $items, $menu, $args ){
    foreach ( $items as $index => $menu_item ){
        // conditional statement to compare the menu-item URL
        if( $menu_item->url ==  get_site_url().'/portfolio/' ){
               $menu_item->classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
        }
    }
  return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'add_class_to_specific_menu_items', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't seem to work for me. While PHP isn't my speciality, how is this adding the class .current-menu-item to the specific menu item I am trying to target (#menu-item-33)?

Comment: The if statement is a place where you can compare the menu-item properties, like URL or id, or title, etc. make it simple, enable the WordPress debugging log, and then add the following code before the if statement.  error_log( print_r($menu_item, true)); and then check the $menu_item array in the debug log file inside wp-content -> debug.log file. Thanks

Comment: Hi - I tried both solutions. Solution 2 I believe is the same as your first answer and unfortunately doesn't do anything (I tried again). Solution 01 adds the required class to  #menu-item-33, however it is always added, but I only want it added when the site url has '/portfolio/' in it. Is there anyway to add another if statement to Solution 01 that only fires when the url is  '/portfolio/' ?

Comment: Sure  @moodyjive, Solution 01 is updated with the current page URL comparison conditional statement. Kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

@modyjive -- the answer @ejaz-ul-haq gave is congruent with your PHP code given. Your PHP code tries to add the `current-menu-item` class to anchors that contain the `/portfolio/` URL in their HREF attribute.  Your code isn't quite right, so @ejaz-ul-haq fixed it up so that it gives the represented effect. But, I'm interpreting your question to mean something different: you want to convert the functionality of the JavaScript provided into something WordPress-able. If that's what you want, here's my answer.

We first determine what your JS does:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {                    // When the page loads,
    var loc = window.location.href;                       // save the current URL
    if(/portfolio/.test(loc)) {                           // and check if it contains '/portfolio/'.
        $('#menu-item-33').addClass('current-menu-item'); // If so, add `current-menu-item` to the class list of all elements with id="menu-item-33"
    }
});
```

Immediately, we run into a problem: your JS will add `current-menu-item` to any and all HTML elements having an `id="menu-item-33"` attribute. So, it will happen in the backend as well as the frontend and in some places you might not even know exist.  I'm going to go out on a limb here, but I'm guessing you're using the `nav_menu_link_attributes` hook because you're trying to manipulate navigation menus printed on the front-end, maybe?  If so, let's dig into the WordPress documentation to see how those are printed out.  (I've provided links in the text below so you can follow along; if you're not familiar with tracing WordPress code, now's your chance to learn.)

First, we figure out a starting point.  You used the `nav_menu_link_attributes` hook, so let's start there. From the [reference guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_link_attributes/#source), it is learned this hook is found in the [/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.1/src/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php) file.  According to the [header notes of the hook](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.1/src/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php#L183), `nav_menu_link_attributes` "Filters the HTML attributes applied to a menu item’s anchor element." The anchor element (`<a>`) is located inside the list item element (`<li>`).  Your JavaScript represents that you want to add a class to the list item element, not the anchor.  If we scroll up to [line 170](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.1/src/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php#L170), we can see where the list item is added to the output stream.  That line looks like this:

```
$output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names . '>';
```

We can see on [lines 167 and 168](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.1/src/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php#L167) where `$id` is generated and on [lines 153 and 154](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.1/src/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php#L153) where `$class_names` is generated. By hooking into the `nav_menu_css_class` filter (on line 153), we can miniplate the `$class_names` variable before it is output in the `<li>` opening tag on line 170, which I believe is what you want! According to the [WordPress reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_css_class/), the `nav_menu_css_class` hook "Filters the CSS classes applied to a menu item’s list item element."  Yup, that's what your JS does, so we're on the right track.

So, here we go:

```
function add_class_to_specific_menu_items($classes, $item, $args, $depth){
    global $wp;
    $loc = add_query_arg($wp->query_vars, home_url($wp->request)); // Save the current URL (like you did in your JS)
    if(stripos($loc, '/portfolio/') !== NULL                       // and check if it contains `/portfolio/`  (like you did in your JS).
    && $item->ID === 33                                            // Also check that this is menu item #33  (like what you did in your JS, but limit only to navigation menus)
    ) {
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';                          // and if so, add the desired class to the list item (like you did in your JS).
    }
    // No matter what, return the $classes array or we'll break things when navigation menus are output.
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_class_to_specific_menu_items', 10, 4);
```

Time for a beer (and hopefully you'll click the answered checkmark, upvote, and give me your bounty).

Comment: Thank for your answer, however I am receiving errors: Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 25 of file wp-content/themes/uncode-child/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again. Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function add_class_to_specific_menu_items(), 3 passed in wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 292 and exactly 4 expected in wp-content/themes/uncode-child/functions.php:25
Stack trace:

Comment: #0 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(292): add_class_to_specific_menu_items(Array, Object(WP_Post), Object(stdClass))
#1 wp-includes/plugin.php(212): WP_Hook->apply_filters(Array, Array)
#2 wp-content/themes/uncode/core/inc/wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php(140): apply_filters('nav_menu_css_cl...', Array, Object(WP_Post), Object(stdClass))
#3 wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php(144): wp_bootstrap_navwalker->start_el('', Object(WP_Post), 0, Object(stdClass))
#4 wp-content/themes/uncode/core/inc/wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php(238): Walker->display_element(Object(WP_Post), Array, 0, 0, Array, '')
#5 /nas/co

Comment: @moodyjive -- You failed to update the filtering line in your `functions.php` file:  you must use the number "4" as demonstrated in my code, not the number "3" as you originally used.

Comment: Thanks, but still got an error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function add_class_to_specific_menu_items(), 3 passed in wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 292 and exactly 4 expected in wp-content/themes/uncode-child/functions.php:24
Stack trace:

Comment: @moodyjive -- The error your are receiving has to do with the code that is in your `functions.php` file on line 24.  The hook is sending 4 arguments and the function you defined only has three:  this error will continue so long you have this conflict in your code.